Error Integrating Flutter Crashlytics: "Runner.xcodeproj does not exist" and "Undefined symbols" in Xcode
I’m integrating Firebase Crashlytics into my Flutter project using the FlutterFire CLI. During this process, I encountered two major issues:

Pod Install Warning:
When I run pod install in the ios directory, I see the following warning:
Project at /Users/hazratbilal/Documents/HHD/Runner.xcodeproj does not exist. Please check paths or incorporate Crashlytics upload symbols manually.

The Runner.xcodeproj file indeed does not exist in that path. My actual path to Runner.xcodeproj is:
/Users/hazratbilal/Documents/HHD softwares/scribemedix-app/ios/Runner.xcodeproj

How can I fix this path issue so that pod install recognizes the correct location?
enter image description here

Xcode Build Error:
When I run the app, I get the following error in Xcode:
Undefined symbols:
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This occurs after I added Firebase Crashlytics to the project.
enter image description here


Steps I Have Taken:

I followed the FlutterFire CLI documentation to set up Crashlytics.
My Podfile includes the following Firebase dependencies:
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'


I verified that GoogleService-Info.plist is added to the ios directory and properly linked in Xcode.
I ensured that flutterfire CLI is installed and configured.

Environment:

Flutter version: flutter --version
Firebase Crashlytics version: (from Podfile.lock, e.g., 10.6.0)
macOS version: uname -a

My Questions:

How do I configure pod install to recognize the correct Runner.xcodeproj path?
What causes the Undefined symbols error in Xcode after adding Firebase Crashlytics, and how can I resolve it?
Do I need to manually upload symbols, or is this handled by the Crashlytics script added by the FlutterFire CLI?

Additional Information:
Here’s my full Podfile for reference:
platform :ios, '13.0'

ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner.xcodeproj', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'

  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

I’d greatly appreciate any help in resolving these issues. Thanks in advance!
